# android application force close on executing this query

Tags: android, sqlite

Hi i am trying to execute this query but every time i run in the emulator, it shows force close message. Someone plz tell me **whats wrong in the query?**

```
 public String searchRecord(String f) {

Cursor cur= db.query(DATABASE_TABLE,new String[] { UserName, Age, Sex,DOB}  , UserName +" like 'sa%'" , null ,null ,null ,null , "5");

 cur.moveToFirst();

 return cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(UserName));

}
```

this is the logcat.

```
06-30 15:02:47.342: WARN/dalvikvm(300): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
06-30 15:02:47.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(300): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-30 15:02:47.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(300): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.text.SpannableStringBuilder
06-30 15:02:47.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(300):     at com.menu.san.OptionsmenuActivity$2.onTextChanged(OptionsmenuActivity.java:66)
06-30 15:02:47.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(300):     at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:6131)
06-30 15:02:47.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(300):     at android.widget.TextView.handleTextChanged(TextView.java:6172)
06-30 15:02:47.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(300):     at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onTextChanged(TextView.java:6316)
06-30 15:02:47.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(300):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendTextChange(SpannableStringBuilder.java:889)
06-30 15:02:47.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(300):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.change(SpannableStringBuilder.java:352)
06-30 15:02:47.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(300):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.change(SpannableStringBuilder.java:269)
06-30 15:02:47.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(300):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:432)
06-30 15:02:47.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(300):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:409)
06-30 15:02:47.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(300):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:28)
06-30 15:02:47.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(300):     at android.text.method.QwertyKeyListener.onKeyDown(QwertyKeyListener.java:195)
06-30 15:02:47.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(300):     at android.text.method.TextKeyListener.onKeyDown(TextKeyListener.java:132)
06-30 15:02:47.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(300):     at android.widget.TextView.doKeyDown(TextView.java:4304)
06-30 15:02:47.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(300):     at android.widget.TextView.onKeyDown(TextView.java:4149)
06-30 15:02:47.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(300):     at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:1037)
06-30 15:02:47.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(300):     at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:3740)
06-30 15:02:47.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(300):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:788)
06-30 15:02:47.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(300):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:788)
06-30 15:02:47.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(300):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:788)
06-30 15:02:47.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(300):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:788)
06-30 15:02:47.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(300):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1667)
06-30 15:02:47.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(300):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1102)
06-30 15:02:47.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(300):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2063)
06-30 15:02:47.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(300):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
06-30 15:02:47.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(300):     at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverKeyEventToViewHierarchy(ViewRoot.java:2471)
06-30 15:02:47.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(300):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleFinishedEvent(ViewRoot.java:2441)
06-30 15:02:47.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(300):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1735)
06-30 15:02:47.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(300):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-30 15:02:47.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(300):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-30 15:02:47.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(300):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
06-30 15:02:47.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(300):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-30 15:02:47.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(300):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-30 15:02:47.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(300):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
06-30 15:02:47.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(300):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
06-30 15:02:47.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(300):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-30 15:02:47.812: WARN/ActivityManager(67):   Force finishing activity com.menu.san/.OptionsmenuActivity
06-30 15:02:48.832: WARN/ActivityManager(67): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{44f35b60 com.menu.san/.OptionsmenuActivity}
```

Answer (score 0):

can you post logcat ?

I think your problem comes the syntaxe of your select argument

try to add the \ like this :

`USER_LOGIN + " LIKE \"" + login +"\""`

Comment: try to catch SQLException when you're calling the cursor. It can provide more information about what's wrong in your query.

Answer (score 0):

Try posting your logcat output and we can probably help further, but on first glance I can see a couple of potential problems:

- If the UsernName column does not exist, `getColumnIndex()` will return -1, which will cause problems with `cur.getString()`
- If your query does not return any results, both `cur.getString` and `cur.getColumnIndex` will fail

I'd suggest you update your code to something like this:

```
public String searchRecord(String f) {
    String user;
    Cursor cur= db.query(DATABASE_TABLE,new String[] { UserName, Age, Sex,DOB} , UserName +" like 'sa%'" , null ,null ,null ,null , "5");
    if ( cur.getCount() > 0 ) { // Only attempt to get the UserName if we actually got some results
        cur.moveToFirst();
        user = cur.getString ( cur.getColumnIndex ( UserName ) );
    }
    else { // If no results returned by the query, return a NULL string;
        user = null;
    }
    return user;
}
```

You may want to consider using `getColumnIndexOrThrow` instead of `getColumnIndex` as it will throw an exception and will make errors relating to missing columns more obvious.

Another question is are you sure that UserName, Age, Sex, and DOB are variables, or are they the actual column name? If they are the literal column name, you should use the following query instead:

```
Cursor cur= db.query(DATABASE_TABLE,new String[] { "UserName", "Age", "Sex", "DOB" } , "UserName like 'sa%'" , null ,null ,null ,null , "5");
```

If so, you should also change your `getColumnIndex` call to:

```
cur.getColumnIndex ( "UserName" )
```

Comment: I have used same names for variables and column name both.

Comment: The logcat you appended suggests the exception is happening when you change the text of a textview - that may still be because of a problem with your query so I'd suggest the changes I mention above and using the getColumnIndexOrThrow variant to identify if the query is the problem.

Comment: I think the problem is occuring while i'm converting charsequence to string. This is the code where i hv converted it.                           public void onTextChanged (CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    String query = td.searchRecord((String)s);
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),query, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

Comment: I still think you need to look at my suggestions for the query - if the query is not working properly, your code may not show it until you try to use the result, hence the problem showing up elsewhere. On a side note, you are not using the argument to searchRecord anywhere - are you expecting to search based on the argument? If so, that is not happening.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to do something like this,it works fine for me:

```
public Cursor SearchRecord(String search) {        
    Cursor c;        
    String[]columns = {UserName, Age, Sex,DOB};
    String Limit = "0,5";

    String query = search != null ? UserName + " LIKE '" + search + "%' " : "";

    c = myDataBase.query(DATABASE_TABLE,columns, query, null, null, null, null, Limit);

    return c;
}
```

Then do anything you waht with the retrieved data in the Cursor